# Why is this distribution function neither discrete nor continuous?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm refreshing some Probability Theory (it's been a while) and came accross the following example:

Let $X$ be a random variable with distributuion function $$F_X(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l r}0 & \text{if }x<0\\\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{2}&\text{if }0\le x<1\\1&\text{if }x\ge 1\end{array}\right.$$
Then this random variable is neither discrete nor continuous, since $$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\frac{1}{2},\quad\text{and}\quad\mathbb{P}(X=\frac{1}{2})=0.$$

Is this first statement true since $X$ takes these values on all $x<0$? And the second statement true since $X$ takes that value for only 1 value of $x$, out of infinitely many?

It's probably easy, but I'm not sure if I understand it...

Comment: What's your understanding of the meaning of both 'discrete' and 'continuous'?

Comment: Plot the CDF. Half of the probability is at $0$ and the other half uniformly distributed on (0,1).

Answer (score 2):

A random variable is continuous if the cdf is a continuous function. This is not continuous at x=0.
A random variable is discrete if it can take only a countable number of values. This can take any value in (0.5,1) which is uncountably infinite.

So it is neither discrete or continuous.

To find $P[X=x]$, find $P[X \le x]=F(x)$ and subtract $P[X<x]$, which is the supremum of $F(y)$ for all $y<x$.  Since $F$ is a non-decreasing function, the supremum is the limit as $y$ approaches $x$ from the left.

Since $P[X\le x]=0$ for all $x<0$,
$$P[X=0]=P[X\le 0]-\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-}P[X \le x]=\frac{1}2$$

On the other hand,
$$P\left[X=\frac{1}2 \right]=
P\left[X \le \frac{1}2 \right]-\lim_{x\rightarrow {\frac{1}2}^-}P\left[X \le x \right]=
 \frac{1}2 +\frac{\frac{1}2}2-\lim_{x\rightarrow {\frac{1}2}^-}\left(\frac{1}2 +\frac{x}2\right)=0$$

Comment: I can understand this. However, this does not help me understand why the probability at the given instance takes these values..

Comment: @DavidW. answer is edited

Answer (score 0):

The **distribution** function, F, is not continuous because the limit, at = 0, "from the left" is 0 while the limit "from the right" is $\frac{1}{2}+ \frac{0}{2}= \frac{1}{2}$.

But the statement that "P(x= 0)= 1/2" is simply WRONG.  $P(x= a)= \int_{-\infty}^a F(x)dx$.  Since F(x)= 0 for x< 0, P(x)= 0 for x< 0  and, if $x\ge 0$ $P(x)= \int_0^x F(x)dx$.

In particular, while F(0)= 1/2, P(0)= 0 since $\int_0^0 F(x)d= 0$ for any F.
And $P(1/2)= \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{x}{2}dx= \left[\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{x^2}{4}\right]_0^{1/2}= \frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{16}= \frac{5}{16}$, not "0".